# sending html string is replacing single quotes with double quotes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, append

when i send from a node.js server string containing some dynamically filled html, using for example Postman to test the GET request i get the correct html:

```
<div class="page_wrapper_home">
    <div data-nanogallery2='{"itemsBaseURL": "../assets/galeria/", "thumbnailWidth": "auto", "thumbnailBorderVertical": 0, "thumbnailBorderHorizontal": 0, "colorScheme": { "thumbnail": { "background": "rgba(0,0,0,0)" } }, "thumbnailDisplayTransition": "flipDown", "thumbnailDisplayTransitionDuration": 750, "thumbnailDisplayInterval": 250, "thumbnailLabel": { "display": false }, "thumbnailHoverEffect2": "toolsAppear|scale120", "galleryDisplayMode": "pagination", "galleryPaginationMode": "numbers", "thumbnailAlignment": "center"}'>
        <a href="boda_01.jpg" data-ngthumb="boda_01_t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">boda_01</a>
        <a href="boda_02.jpg" data-ngthumb="boda_02_t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">boda_02</a>
        <a href="boda_03.png" data-ngthumb="boda_03_t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">boda_03</a>
        <a href="boda_05.jpg" data-ngthumb="boda_05_t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">boda_05</a>
        <a href="boda_06.jpg" data-ngthumb="boda_06_t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">boda_06</a>
        <a href="boda_04.jpg" data-ngthumb="boda_04_t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">boda_04</a>
        <a href="boda_07.jpg" data-ngthumb="boda_07_t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">boda_07</a>
        <a href="boda_08.jpg" data-ngthumb="boda_08_t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">boda_08</a>
        <a href="boda_09.jpg" data-ngthumb="boda_09_t.jpg" data-ngdesc="">boda_09</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

but when i use `JQuery's append()` method, `single quotes are subtituted by double quotes`, and `double quotes are substituted by &quot;`, so it's only showing double quotes throughout the whole section. how can i do this so i get the exact same markup?

Comment: Can you show us the logic around the append that is resulting in this behavior?

Comment: I cannot replicate this; everything works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/zxm5pref/ (I'd change the entire approach though: GET JSON from the server, then build the elements)

Comment: @ChrisG maybe is only chrome dev tools the one that substitutes single with double quotes? if you check it in your jsfiddle with chrome dev tools it shows single quotes as double quotes.  that's why i thought it wasn't working in the first place.

Comment: @Taplar there's not much code around the append except for an ajax call to get that html string, which is made dynamically on the server. maybe is just a chrome dev tools thing :/ wierd

Comment: yeah, it's not working, all data (which are the config for a js gallery) between the single quotes, are not beint taken in consideration. The gallery is working, but not applying the configs... so the quotes are still a problem.